# Checking elements' existence within an iterator in python

Tags: python, iterator

When we are using an iterator, the elements pops out by order, then how do we check if a guessing element within the iterator or not? In my code only `in` seems to work:

```
t = "cawqv"
it = iter(t)

print(next(it))
print("a" in it)
print("w" is it) 
print("w" == it)
print("w" in it)
>>
c
True
False
False
True
```

`is` is unlikely to work in the case since it checks whether two objects are the same object, but `==` only cares their value, like `equals()` method in Java. 
Is the `in` operator the only one we can use to check element existence within an iterator?

Comment: `"abc" != iter("abc")` for the same reason that `"abc" != ("a", "b", "c")`.  Two objects both being iterable doesn't make them comparable

Comment: `"w" == it` do not work because `it` holds the iterator object and not every element of it or the current element pointed by `__next__` method

Answer (score 2):

`"w" == it` is checking if `w` (a string) equals your iterator which is obviously `False` as your iterator encapsulates a sequence which may or may not contain `w`. To check for existence of an element using equality you'll have to actually iterate over your iterator and then check if any of the elements encountered during the iteration equals your search element, i.e.:

```
print(any(i == "w" for i in it))
```

but that's what `print("w" in it)` internally does, anyway. Keep in mind that the above **will** exhaust (partially on match, completely if the element is not matched) your iterator, just like `"w" in it` does, because you need to iterate over an iterator to determine if any of the elements matches your search element, e.g.

```
t = "cawqv"
it = iter(t)
print("w" in it)  # True
print("w" in it)  # False - we're pass the `w` point by now
print("q" in it)  # False - we already exhausted our iterator
```